# Can a header be continuous across the whole wall if it is above the top plate?

Tags: framing, structural, construction, design, lumber

I have seen that continuous headers can be problematic due to lateral forces. However, in my situation the "header" is actually a 4x6 purlin which is above the top plate.

[image]

The original purpose of the purlin is to support the oversized overhang on the left (2'). But after putting it into the design I realized it was redundant to have a 4x6 above the windows followed by a 2x6 header above each window, so I removed the individual headers above each window. Is having a continuous header like this problematic in this case?

Comment: I would say a single would be better than multiples that is a load bearing wall,  over hang or not would require a header. In either case there would be concern with shear forces. If you live in an earthquake zone or high wind area the county may want a engineering stamp on the design.

Comment: I agree, this would take some engineering given that there are only 3 walls here as well.